# Component is not detected in MonkeyTalk

Tags: monkeytalk

I have used `achartengine` api in my android application for chart but MonkeyTalk is not able to detect this component, so for that what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If there are any components not getting detected using "Record" option, try the component tree button on the monkeytalk IDE which lists the component's type and monkeyId from which you can make an mtcommand and use it to playback.
For example, if there is a listview with its id, set to "myListView", then you can formulate the mt command as "ListView myListView selectIndex 0"
You can find command references and its actions at

https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-language-reference/command-reference

If still didn't work, try to contact monkeytalk for their QuickStart programs:
https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk/forum

Comment: I have tried all the things and already posted on the forum but didn't get any answer.

Comment: If your project is dependent upon another project which is not instrumented with monkey talk jar.Then you would not be able to see the components of that project anyway.This is how it works.